# How can I send all coin from bitcoind in one command without being manually involved?

Tags: bitcoind, sendtoaddress

I have tried with the commands below

```
sendtoaddress <address> `bitcoin-cli getbalance` "" "" true
sendtoaddress <address> "bitcoin-cli getbalance" "" "" true
sendtoaddress <address> bitcoin-cli getbalance "" "" true
sendtoaddress <address> getbalance "" "" true
sendtoaddress <address> *.* "" "" true
```

But none worked

```
error: Error parsing JSON:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to send all wallet funds in a single-line command.

In a **Unix shell**, this should work:

```
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <address> $(bitcoin-cli getbalance) "" "" true
```

The **Windows command prompt** doesn't support the substitution via backticks or $(…), but I'm [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226480/1364089) that you should be able to use a [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop with the `usebackq` option to emulate it:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`bitcoin-cli getbalance`) do bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <address> %A "" "" true
```

I have no Windows machine and have *not tested* this, I suggest you verify carefully and use at own risk.

Starting with the next release, **Bitcoin Core v24**, you will be able to use `sendall`:

```
bitcoin-cli sendall '["<address>"]' null "unset" <feerate (s/vB)>
```

Comment: i have tried your command on v0.21.1.
`bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <address> $(bitcoin-cli getbalance) "" "" true`
but none worked
`error: Error parsing JSON: $(bitcoin-cli`

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: i am running Command Prompt from bat file

Comment: That explains it! I've amended my suggestion. I don't use Windows, it's not tested, please verify carefully, use at own risk